# Few Instance of object Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a few instance of this class

```
var fruit = {
    texture: new Image(),
    speed: 5,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
};
function fruits(speed, x, y) 
{
    fruit.speed = speed;
    fruit.x = x;
    fruit.y = y;
    return fruit;
};
```

but when i create new object the all value was overridet by last created object. How can i repair this?
My loop:

```
var apples = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    apples[i] = new fruits(5, Math.floor((Math.random()*775)+1), 0);
    apples[i].texture.src = "_img/apple.png";
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `apples` as an array? Make sure you do it outside the scope of the `for loop`.

Comment: a constructor should use `this.blah` as attributes, not an external object, and it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: Are you trying to use a factory pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers which are appearing here are just bizarre. Here's the solution:

```
function fruits(speed, x, y) 
{
    this.texture = new Image( );
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
```

Notice that the keyword `this` is used to set attributes. That means that when you call

```
var apple = new fruits( blah blah );
```

then `apple` will be set to a new object which has `texture`, `speed`, `x` and `y` attributes. There is no need to reference some global object to store these; they are stored in the newly created object itself.

Also I would rename it; the convention is to use singular names and a capital first letter for objects, so `Fruit` would make more sense (allowing `new Fruit(...)`)

Answer (score 2):

```
function Fruit( speed, x, y ){
    var fruit = {};   // or use some base object instead of {}

    fruit.texture = new Image();
    fruit.speed   = speed || 5;
    fruit.x       = x || 0;
    fruit.y       = y || 0;

    return fruit;
};

var apples = [];

for( var i=0; i<10; i++ ){        
    apples[i] = Fruit( 5, Math.floor((Math.random()*775)+1), 0 );
    apples[i].texture.src = "_img/apple.png";
}
```

[Douglas Crockford - Power Constructor, 'new', 'this' and more](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwYPG6vreJg)

Answer (score 1):

You got an object here:

```
var fruit = {
    texture: new Image(),
    speed: 5,
    x: 0,
    y: 0, // Note the superflous comma, which might break the code in some IE versions
};
```

And a function here:

```
function fruits(speed, x, y)  {
    fruit.speed = speed;
    fruit.x = x;
    fruit.y = y;
    return fruit;
};
```

The function modifies above object whenever it is called and returns it.

Now, what you want is a constructor, but you don't have one here.

This, would be a constructor for a new `Fruit`:

```
function Fruit(speed, x, y) {
    this.texture = new Image();
    this.speed = speed || 5; // Note: Using logical OR to emulate default values for the argument
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;

    // Note: There is no return here!
}

var a = new Fruit(2, 1, 10);
var b = new Fruit(4, 10, 20);
a === b; // Returns false, you got two instances :)
```

`new` may have the functionality of being able to create instances of a `Function`, but you can still override this behavior by returning manually from within the `constructor` Function.

Also, even if you left out the `return fruit` in your original code, you would get back an empty instance of `fruits` since you don't assign any properties to the newly created instance.

In my `Fruit` example I reference the `instance object` via the `this` keyword, so I can assign `speed`, `image`, `x` and `y` to each instance created.

You might also want to read:

- http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.constructors
- http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Answer (score 0):

```
function fruits(speed, x, y) {
    return {
        texture: new Image(),
        speed: speed,
        x: x,
        y: x,
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try such constructor:

```
function Fruit(speed, x, y) {
    return {
        speed: speed,
        x: x,
        y: y
    }
}

alert(new Fruit("mySpeed", 1, 2).speed);
```

Comment: I have already written the same. You forgot texture parameter.